# Mongo bulk update inputed array key value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

i am using aggregation to update all records depend from provided array keys and values

```
db.getCollection('testBulk').aggregate([ {$addFields:{"test":{$cond: [ { $in: [ "$test", [-1,11] ] }, {$arrayElemAt: [ ["ass", "abdc"],{$indexOfArray: [ [-1,11  ], "$test" ]} ]}, "$test" ]}}} ,{ $out: 'testBulk' } ])
```

here in this query iam updating field `test` depend from input values array `[-1,11]` and set up new value from `["ass", "abdc"]`. Any help to keep inputed arrays into variable so not declaring them for each updated record. Inputed arrays can be over 10k length

Collection example

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc0106ec735877097dc194e"),
    "test" : -1, 
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc01076c735877097dc1950"),
    "test" : 11, 
}
```

After run the query above will have

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc0106ec735877097dc194e"),
    "test" : "ass", 
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc01076c735877097dc1950"),
    "test" : "abdc", 
}
```

Comment: Include a sample document, and expected output or this won't work

Comment: also, mongoDB has 16MB document size limit. Don't create unbounded arrays, or you'll have all sort of troubles in the future.

Comment: how we can bind the arrays(inputed data) to mongo aggregation. Is there some possibility to declare the arrays or temporary save them in temp db than use in agregation?